# Write a program that adds together all the integers from `1` to `250` (inclusive) and `puts`es the total

Tags: ruby

How would I do this using ruby and only using a while loop with if, elsif and else only?

Comment: @NathanHughes it's probably an exercise.

Comment: Is the result of `puts "puts #{(1..250).to_a.join(' + ')}"` acceptable?

Comment: _"only using a while loop with if, elsif and else"_ – that's hardly possible. A `while` loop with assignment, addition and comparison operator would work. Maybe you can clarify your requirements.

Comment: So your instructor is actively steering you away from actual Ruby solutions such as `puts (1..250).inject(&:+)`?

Comment: @pjs: `(1..250).sum` is probably even more Ruby-ish, *and* is much faster – O(1), in fact.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I don't doubt you on relative speed, but the `inject` approach is also O(1) since 250 is a constant.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need a while loop to implement this. But if they want a while loop…

```
n = 250
while true
    puts ( n * (n + 1)) / 2
    break
end
```

Some of the comments have alternatives that are interesting, but this one because  has the flow of control at least pass through the while loop. Not sure if it counts as using a loop if control doesn't even enter the body of the loop.

Comment: The requirement in the question is "only using a while loop with if, elsif and else only", but you are message sending, local variable assignment, local variable dereference, `Integer` literals, the `Integer#+` method, the `Integer#*` method, the `Integer#/` method, the `Integer#to_s` method (implicitly), the `FalseClass#!` method, the `TrueClass#!` method, and probably lots of other things that are not allowed by the question.

Comment: @Jorg: True. But we can’t call puts without some kind of conversion. So the question has assumptions that could be more explicit.

Comment: Even shorter: `while puts n * (n + 1) / 2 ; end` (abusing the fact that `puts` has a falsey return value)

Comment: @Stefan: even shorter then: `() while puts n * (n + 1) / 2` :)

Comment: …or `while false; end; puts ( n * (n + 1)) / 2`.

Comment: Nathan, I see you anticipated my comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
sum = 0
i = 1

while i < 251
   sum += i
   i += 1
end

puts sum
```

Comment: The requirement in the question is "only using a while loop with if, elsif and else only", but you are message sending, local variable assignment, local variable dereference, `Integer` literals, the `Integer#+` method, the `Integer#to_s` method (implicitly), and probably lots of other things that are not allowed by the question.